# "bulkNote request failed with Proton code 65561" by creating a document

Tags: javascript, domino-appdev-pack

im currently doing the quick-start of domino-db and when i tried to create a document i got an internal error with the error message "bulkNote request failed with Proton code 65561".

Do you know what the problem is and is it possible to check some logs of proton to see what went wrong.

```
const serverConfig   = {
    hostName  : 'XXXXXXX.de', // Host name of and port are valid
    connection: {
        port: 'XXXX',
    },
};
const databaseConfig = {
    filePath: 'node-demo.nsf', // The database file name
};    
useServer(serverConfig)
.then((server) => server.useDatabase(databaseConfig))
.then((database) => database.createDocument({
    document: {
        Form: 'Contact',
        FirstName: 'Aaron',
        LastName: 'Aardman',
        City: 'Arlington',
        State: 'MA',
    },
}))
.catch(console.error);
```

edit:
The error appears every time i access a document(document.read, bulkReadDocuments) not only by the creation of a document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the definition of that error code (from errorcodes.js):

```
65561: { id: 'INVALID_SQN', msg: 'Invalid or missing protocol sequence number.' },
```

This suggests you are using the Beta version of domino-db with the latest release of Proton. Proton now checks the protocol sequence number for every request -- to make sure it's not an incompatible request from a newer client. The Beta version of domino-db did not send the sequence number.

Please check your app and make sure it's using the latest version of domino-db.